# Git - Moving a local branch to different remote branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I want to move my local branch, from one remote branch to another. my local_branch is based on remotes/kernel/132, and I move it to the remotes/kernel/142. Here is the list of my branches:

```
git branch -a
* local_branch 
remotes/kernel/132
remotes/kernel/142
```

I already changed some part of the code, and have committed. However, I don't want to push the local_branch to the remotes/kernel/132, but I want to move it to remotes/kernel/142 and push it to this remote branch. 
The config file shows this:

```
[branch "local_branch"]
    remote = kernel
    merge = refs/heads/132
```

I want to change it to:

```
[branch "local_branch"]
    remote = kernel
    merge = refs/heads/142
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Moving" the commits is called a `rebase`.  This doesn't *really* move the commits, but it creates new commits on the new base, which apply the same changes as the old commits applied to the old base.  The ref does move (from the old commits to the new ones); and since you haven't pushed these commits (and presumably don't have other refs that can reach them) it's a textbook instance where rebasing should work pretty cleanly.

```
git rebase --onto kernel/142 kernel/132 local_branch
```

The new commits represent untested states of the code, so some testing is in order at this point.

The other part of the question you can handle with `git config`

```
git config branch.local_branch.merge refs/heads/142
```